# using PDO with php and mysql in class

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

i am trying to use PDO in php using classes.

so i have defined one config file like that

```
<?php
global $configVars;

    $configVars['online'] = false;  

    if(($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])!='localhost' and ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])!='abc')
    {
$configVars['dbhost']       = "localhost";      
$configVars['dbuser']       = "dbuser";   
$configVars['dbpassword']   = "dbpass";     
$configVars['dbname']       = "dbname"; 

}
?>
```

then i have defined class to connect the database

```
<?php
class dbClass{
var $dbHost,
      $dbUser,
        $dbName,
          $dbPass,
            $dbTable,
              $dbLink,
                $resResult,
                  $dbh,
                  $dbPort;  


        function dbClass(){
            global $configVars;
            $this->dbHost = $configVars['dbhost'];
            $this->dbUser = $configVars['dbuser'];
            $this->dbPass = $configVars['dbpassword'];
            $this->dbName = $configVars['dbname'];
            $this->connect_PDO();
        }

        function connect_PDO(){
            try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->dbHost.';dbname='.$this->dbName.'', $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected.";
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "I'm sorry Charlie, I'm afraid i cant do that.";
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
            $dbh = null;
            }
        }
 }
```

?>

now i have defined another class to select the records from table

```
<?
class cms extends dbClass
{

function get_rec($id=0)
    {
        ($id==0?$addQuery="":$addQuery=" where id =".$id);
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("select * from TABLENAME :name order by id");
        $statement->execute(array(':name' => $addQuery));
        $row = $statement->fetchAll(); 
        return $row ;
    }   


}
?>
```

now when i am using this function in my PHP file like this

```
<?php 
$objCMS=new cms();
$getCMS=$objCMS->get_rec(1);
echo $getCMS[0];
?>
```

i got following out put

```
Connected.
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
```

i am trying to sort this out from last 2 days but no success.

i am new to PDO and want to use it.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by this statement `select * from TABLENAME :name order by id`?

Comment: your constructor is not being executed. See my answer

Comment: Dear @John Woo TableName is name of table and :name is value of parameter where i am trying to pass "where id=passedvale"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `dbClass()` in your constructor for `cms`

add this to the `cms` class

```
function cms() {
    parent::dbClass();
}
```

and change `get_rec` to have:

```
$statement = $this->dbh->prepare("select * from TABLENAME :name order by id");
```

when using `$dbh` you need to reference it as `$this->dbh`

You need to make the `$dbh` to `$this->dbh` changes in you need to update `connect_PDO()` also

Comment: i think i have define it ($dbh) already and its Global, can you please tell me how to define it again?

Comment: where did you define it as global and how? In the code you have posted it's not defined in global scope

Comment: I updated my answer. It appears your `cms` class is not executing the parent constructor upon instantiation

Comment: no its still same even if i add this function in my cms class and if i put parent::dbClass(); in function get_rec, i got connect printed 2 times but other error same

Comment: dont put parent::dbClass in get_rec

Comment: Dear , thanks for update but still same error... i have added a new function my class function cms and also change line $this-> but still same error

Comment: you need to update `connect_PDO()` to use `$this->dbh` instead of `$dbh`

Comment: Thanks, this solve the old error but new error come Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() , and if use $this->$dbh->setAttribute i got other error Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in

Comment: use `$this->dbh->setAttribute` You had an extra `$` in there

Comment: Thanks and this solve my problem, please tell me am i secure approach for DB connection and selection to avoid any hacker attack and SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

You $dbh is declared in the base class but without a specific scope I think it's going to default to 'private'. Hence not visible in the sub class.

Also you aren't calling the constructor. Add a call to 'parent::__construct()' in your sub class.   http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 1):

You are going in wrong direction about solving this one.

If you want to give some object access to database, then that object needs access to database object that provides methods to interact with the database. You got that right.

But, inheritance is "IS A" relationship. And your CMS object is not a database type of object, and doesn't have same function as database object right? CMS object should just use Database and this is called composition. This relationship is also called "HAS A" relationship.

So instead of using Inheritance here, you should use Composition like this:

```
class CMS
{
    protected $db;
    // other CMS related stuff
}

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$cms = new User($db);
```

This way your CMS can use database without using inheritance.

- Google about composition vs. inheritance and when to use it.
- Also take a look at this answer here:
  [PHP Mysqli Extension Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276315/php-mysqli-extension-warning/13276735#13276735)
- And read this article and go through examples to understand why
  composition is a way to go when providing some class a way to
  interact with database.

I know this is not an answer to your question, but you have gone in the wrong direction to solve your problems. I see lots of people use only inheritance so just be aware that there is much more then inheritance to make your objects interact. And in this situation, its just wrong to use Inheritance since your CMS object has nothing to do with Database, they are not the same "type". CMS should only use Database.

Hope this helps!